# Is it possible to auto-detect classes and to generate types for generics at compile time?

Tags: java, generics, callback, retrofit2

Suppose there are three classes *MyClass1*, *MyClass2*, *MyClass3* existing in package *com.my.package*. In a method elsewhere I try to create a generic type instance where each class represents the type of the Callback exactly once:

```
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyClass1>(){...});
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyClass2>(){...});
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyClass3>(){...});
```

Instead of typing in each class by hand, I want to achieve auto-detection of classes in a specific package and subsequently create a generic of this type.

This feature is desired because classes could be added or deleted in *com.my.package* and I don't want to change code elsewhere. Even if I have access to a List of *java.lang.Class* objects, I still cannot generate types for generics out of *Class* objects. I know the type of a generic cannot be declared at runtime (so reflection is out), however, in my view all required information are available at compile time yet.

Is there a way to achieve this?

(In my application I work with Retrofit, Gson needs the concrete type of the POJO in the angle brackets in order to parse the JSON data. The underlying model is quite complex and can change.)

Comment: If you are working with `Retrofit` and `Gson`, in your callback `response.getBody()` already give you the instance of your class

Comment: Yes, but I have to predetermine the type when calling `call.enqueue(new Callback<TypeOfResponseIWannaHave>(){...})`

Comment: You want generic callback for all of your `Call<...>` api?

Comment: Why do you need to initialize? You just get instance from your response. You're not supposed to create the response

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to create the response anyway. You have to get the response instance from API:

```
public class MyCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            T body = response.body(); // This is your response instance
        } else {
            // 404/500... error
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
        // fail
    }
}
```

Comment: Still I need to tell Retofit the type of the object where the json data should be written into. When enqueuing MyCallback<T> T must be a defined type. In my ApiService interface I want to have just one method like

`@GET("/{endpoint}")
    Call<? extends AbstractDataComponent> getElement(String endpoint);`

instead of declaring `Call<Project> getProject, Call<Partner> getPartner, Call<Offer> getOffer etc. individually